# Hyperlink button click in WinPhone 7 Emulator gives error - "Can't Send, Make sure you have setup an account"

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, emulation

I have a C# project for Windows Phone 7 that I created with Expression Blend and Visual Studio 2012. I have an About page with a Hyperlink button that takes the user to the support web page for the app.  When I click the button I get a screen in the Emulator saying:

"Can't Send.  Make sure you have set up an account."

This ends up triggering a NULL argument exception in System.Windows.ni.dll in the VS2012 debugger.  There is no View Exception Details option visible.  I have triple-checked the **NavigateUri** value and I know it is a valid web page.  I tried "http://google.com/" just to be sure and I still get the error so it's a more fundamental problem than the URL. Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**: I am showing the XAML for the button in response to Den's reply.  I did not enter the XAML manually, I used the Property Editor window.  I believe the problem is that it is being treated as an E-mail command and I have not set up an E-mail service yet.

Here is the XAML for the HyperLink button:

```
<HyperlinkButton 
            Grid.Row="3" 
            Content="Technical Support/Feedback Email" 
            Margin="0,0,0,23" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" 
            Command="{Binding SendAnEmailCommand}" Width="446" NavigateUri="http://google.com/"/>
```

However, **after removing the Command binding** I now get an Exception from the underlying **Navigate** call the hyperlink button triggers.  I get an Argument Exception with the following error message:

*System.ArgumentException: Navigation is only supported to relative URIs that are fragments, or begin with '/', or which contain ';component/'.  Parameter name: uri
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.Navigate(Uri source)} 
      System.Exception 
      {System.ArgumentException}*

It seems like the Hyperlink button isn't meant for external URIs?  This seems really strange to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're doing something wrong when declaring the `HyperlinkButton`. Here is what it should be like:

```
<HyperlinkButton TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="http://www.microsoft.com" Content="Microsoft"/>
```

Comment: I have added the XAML for the Hyperlink button and run some more tests.  Please comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Set the target name (`TargetName`) - check my snippet.

Comment: Thanks.  Got it now and it works using your info.  This is a rare case where the Property Editor is not your friend, at least for external links and the HyperLink button.  I'll know what to do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Or hey why dont you try making the urikind property to absolute? Test with this and tell me.